# Method in TFS API that is equivalent to tf info in command prompt

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to find the tfs api method that returns the same results as tf info does in command prompt.

I am specifically looking for information regarding the lock and lock owner, changeset number and maybe last modified.

I have tried the following but they don't seem to deliver the results I need.

```
var test1 = vcs.GetItem(file);
```

This returns some information about the file on the server but nothing about the current lock or lock owner.

Also I have tried

```
PendingSet[] test = vcs.QueryPendingSets(new[] {file}, RecursionType.None, null,null);
```

This returns nothing which I am assuming because it's not checked out, but the TF info command will still return results regarding the lock and lock owner it would just be blank.

Here is a sample of what TF info returns.

```
Local information:
  Local path : blah
  Server path: blah
  Changeset  : blah
  Change     : blah
  Type       : blah
Server information:
  Server path  : blah
  Changeset    : blah
  Deletion ID  : blah
  Lock         : none
  Lock owner   :
  Last modified: blah
  Type         : blah
  File type    : blah
  Size         : blah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf info` uses VersionControlServer.GetItems to retrieve Changeset (ChangesetId) and Last Modified (CheckinDate). It uses Workspace.GetExtendedItems (local path) or VersionControlServer.GetExtendedItems (server path) to retrieve LockStatus and LockOwnerDisplayName.

Comment: The GetExtended Items was exactly wqhat I was looking for, thanks!